# is there a way using mule 3 to down load a file from the browser?

Tags: mule

from an api response, I got an url for a downloadable file. when placed this url in the browser, I can download the file. How to perform this action using a Mule 3.9 application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mule [HTTP Request connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/0.3.9/http-request-connector) to send the equivalent request from a Mule flow.